# How to make part of a view controller SKScene and use both on the same screen?

Tags: swift, skscene, skview

I try to make a view controller, where i.e top half of the screen is SKScene, and bottom half of the screen is normal scene, I mean with buttons etc. Is this possible? I created a Single View application, and I am adding some code snippets below, which is the code from viewcontroller.swift file. But it doesn't create boxes to the tapped locations and also it doesn't move as expected a free fall motion when tapped. Maybe is there an issue about that I created a Single view application rather than choosing Game application when first creating the project? Maybe Metal enable/disable needed? I am not professional, therefore just guesses.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
    }
    
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    
    let box = SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: CGSize(width: 0.04, height: 0.04))
    box.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: box.frame.size)
    box.position = location
    addChild(box)
}
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            scene.backgroundColor = .clear
            let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)
            view.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
        }
        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
        view.allowsTransparency = true
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You'll have to anchor a "SKView"  to the top of your view and add your UI below it. Depending on your skill level you may consider the "easy" solution of adding it to a storyboard in the Main.storyboard file, you'll have to: Open the file; click the "+"-button in the upper right corner and search for "SKView"; drag it into the white rectangle; to interface with it and other views I'll recommend Apples tutorial at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/BuildABasicUI.html which covers the basics of creating an iOS app.

Comment: @Harcker I am not that much newbie. Can you explain what is wrong on this code snippet? It doesn't function, even if I can add boxes by tapping, I cannot make them fall motion. I think the problem is about the line SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: OR SKPhysicsBody(edgeloopfrom: OR something else is needed. There is no explanation about all this params. I want the boxes having masses and free fall motion and collide at bottom screen.